# Change HTML table cell background color using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am just beginning using Angular JS in my project.

I have been searching for a way to change the background color from a HTML table cell depending on the value of an Angular JS expression, but haven't found the solution yet.

This is the cell:

```
<td>{{data.material_or_service}</td>
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: see `ng-class` which allows you to set a class to a DOM element with condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `ng-class` : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Example:

css:

```
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

angular view:

```
<td ng-class="{'red': (variable == 1), 'blue': (variable ==2)}">{{data.material_or_service}</td>
```

EDIT:

Try that first:

```
<div ng-class="{'red' : (test != null)}">
  hey !
</div>

<div ng-class="{'red' : (test == null)}">
  hey 2 !
</div>
```

and set up `.red { background-color: red; }` in the css. Hey2 is supposed to be in red.

EDIT 2:

Now try with :

```
<table>
<tr>
<td ng-class="{'red' : (test == null)}">
  hey !
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The `<td>` is red.

Comment: Thank you Pierre, and instead of variable? I am trying as follows:  <td ng-class="{red: (material_or_service == 1), blue: (material_or_service ==2)}">{{data.material_or_service}}</td> and nothing changes, only the value for {{data.material_or_service}} is shown

Comment: @mvasco: I updated the post to give you an example to insert in the code to allow you to test with <div> . The problem is that I failed, it's `'red'` and not `red` in the ng-class ... (my bad, sorry) . In the js console you should have had an error.

Comment: But not the line:  <td ng-class="{'red': (material_or_service == 1), 'blue': (material_or_service ==2)}">{{data.material_or_service}}</td>

Comment: @mvasco: edited to add the 2nd try: it works for a td, so I bet material_or_service has a wrong value. Try to put a `{{  material_or_service | json }} before your <table>, to see its value.`

Comment: Checked and the value is "1", as expected.

Comment: @mvasco: check in the element inspector if you have the class "red" added to that td element. If true, it's a css problem, you have a property which is more important than `red`. Try that too: `{{ material_or_service == 1 | json }}` , I think it will be false if material_or_service is a string `"1"` and not an integer `1`

Comment: Yes, it is a string not an integer.

Comment: @mvasco: so the test is  `(material_or_service == "1")` and not `(material_or_service == 1)`  ;)

Comment: Thank you Pierre, I have accepted your answer, but it is not working changing 1 to "1".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99439/discussion-between-pierre-emmanuel-lallemant-and-mvasco).