# angular change td back gound color if by value

Tags: angular

there was only angularjs for this and it didnt work for me 
trying to set the td back ground color if type ==1 ( can be 1 or 2)
the html of my angular

```
 <div *ngIf="truck" style="overflow-x:auto;">
       <table border = "1" >
        <tr>   
         <th>truckid</th>
         <th>year</th>
         <th>type</th>
         <th>1</th>
         <th>2</th>
         <th>3</th>
         <th>4</th>
         <th>5</th>
         <th>6</th>
         <th>7</th>
         <th>8</th>
         <th>9</th>
         <th>10</th>
         <th>11</th>
         <th>12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let tobj of truck">
    
         <td>{{tobj.truckid}} </td>
         <td>{{tobj.year}}</td>
         <td> {{tobj.type}} </td>
          <td *ngFor="let t1 of tobj.arr">
              {{t1.income}}</td>
        </tr>  
      </table>
    </div>
```

tryd this:
[Change HTML table cell background color using Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552504/change-html-table-cell-background-color-using-angular-js)

but did not work for me
new to angular

**update:**

 my css:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.black {
  color: black;
}
.some-class {
  background-color: #ff2244;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `style.backgroundColor` property of the element directly, or conditionally add a class using `ngClass`

Direct:

```
<td [style.backgroundColor]="tobj.type === 1 ? '#FFFFFF : #000000'"> {{tobj.type}} </td>
```

NgClass:

```
<td [ngClass]="{ 'some-class': tobj.type === 1 }"> {{tobj.type}} </td>
```

CSS with ngClass Example:

```
.some-class {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: <td [ngClass]="{ 'some-class': tobj.type === 1 }"> {{tobj.type}} </td>
i added the css and this not working

Comment: I've created a very minimal example to show you how it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ngclass-ded767bg?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: thx got it to work now :) not sure what i did wrong the first time ,ps the other one work for me to with the function but i did read its better to use the ngclass so il go with it

Answer (score 0):

We can have something like below:

```
<div *ngIf="truck" style="overflow-x:auto;">
       <table border = "1" >
        <tr>   
         <th>truckid</th>
         <th>year</th>
         <th>type</th>
         <th>1</th>
         <th>2</th>
         <th>3</th>
         <th>4</th>
         <th>5</th>
         <th>6</th>
         <th>7</th>
         <th>8</th>
         <th>9</th>
         <th>10</th>
         <th>11</th>
         <th>12</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let tobj of truck">
    
         <td>{{tobj.truckid}} </td>
         <td>{{tobj.year}}</td>
         <td [ngClass]="getColorCode(tobj.type)"> {{tobj.type}} </td>
          <td *ngFor="let t1 of tobj.arr">
              {{t1.income}}</td>
        </tr>  
      </table>
    </div>
```

And at ts file , define the method like below :

```
def getColorCode(type) {
 if(type==1 || type==2) {
    classname = "<some-color-as-class>"; // some-color-as-class is a placeholder:)
 } 
 return classname;
}
```

And at css , define below code:

```
<some-color-name-as-class> {
  color: red; // as per your wish
}
```

Comment: Don't use functions in your template, they are called on every tick, which can lead to serious performance issues. Use `pure` pipes or simply check the condition itself in the template.

Comment: it works but il go with the ngclass ( i think this better )  thx

Comment: Sure Mike, I was not aware about this, thanks for letting me to know this :)

Comment: I followed Pipes at one my component , interestingly it was much faster than it was before (Before this , I used functions at template) - Thanks again